# How can I add zones into MySQL database using leaflet?

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax, leaflet

I created an admin interface where user can add some markers(hospitals, school) and now I want to extend the app for drawing polygons(parks, some zones). The thing is that I successfully connected the map and I can draw polygons, but I can't get the coordinates and add them to database. How can I do this? Thanks!

Comment: Are you using https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw?

Comment: Yes @anatoly.sukhanov

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this : https://bl.ocks.org/danswick/d30c44b081be31aea483

The interesting part :

```
var featureGroup = L.featureGroup().addTo(map);

var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
    edit: {
        featureGroup: featureGroup
    }
}).addTo(map);

map.on('draw:created', function(e) {

    // Each time a feature is created, it's added to the feature group
    featureGroup.addLayer(e.layer);
});

// When you click on the button export
document.getElementById('export').onclick = function(e) {
    // Extract GeoJson from featureGroup
    var data = featureGroup.toGeoJSON();

    // Stringify the GeoJson
    var convertedData = 'text/json;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(data));

    // Create export
    document.getElementById('export').setAttribute('href', 'data:' + convertedData);
    document.getElementById('export').setAttribute('download','data.geojson');
}
```

You only have to adapt the last section with your database.

Comment: It doesn't work for me, the thing is I'm a newbie at this and I don't understand a lot of things

Comment: Let's say what I have. If I click on console, I see: shapes [polyline: Array(1)] and if I scroll deep I can see the latitude and the longitude. I tried with JSON.stringify(shapes), but it doesn t work

Comment: Do you have Facebook or Google+ to talk more easily?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a set of handlers for specific events so that when a polygon is created, edited etc., you get an array of its points and do whatever you need.

```
map.on(L.Draw.Event.CREATED, function (e) {
    map.addLayer(e.layer);
    var points = e.layer.getLatLngs();
    ...
});
```

Comment: Done this, but still didn't showed me this.. It shows me something like this: shapes [polyline: Array(1), circle: Array(0), marker: Array(0)]

Comment: So yeah, I have the points, but how can I add them to a text field and then sent them to database and show them to a edit page?